# Display scrollview button click event

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-button, android-scrollview

I have images under scrollview. I have a button to click event. When i click the button i need to display scrollview. But when i install app the scrollview is automatically displaying bottom of the page.

code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Scroll" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access1"


                 />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@drawable/access2"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access3"
                 />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access4"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access5"
                 />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access6"
                 />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access7"
                 />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/access8"
                 />


        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>



    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Button click:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HorizontalScorllView    srl=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);      

            }



        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default set visiblity of android:id="@+id/scrl" as invisible in xml.
After click on  button
HorizontalScorllView    srl=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
set visiblity of srl as visble.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the HorizontalScrollView to be invisible:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp" >
```

and in your onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

     HorizontalScorllView    srl=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);  
     srl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```